# Replicate a modified du command in python

Tags: python, shell, grep, command

Here is the command I execute in shell. I want to get the same results in Python. Can I do this using the `os` module and how? I'm using `grep -v` here as some file names also have that pattern. Please note that i dont want to invoke this from shell.

```
du -ah 2> >(grep -v "permission denied") |grep [1-9][0-9]G | grep -v [0-9][0-9]K|grep -v [0-9][0-9]M|sort -nr -k 1| head -50
```

Comment: `import subprocess; subprocess.check_output('du -ah 2> >(grep -v "permission denied") |grep [1-9][0-9]G | grep -v [0-9][0-9]K|grep -v [0-9][0-9]M|sort -nr -k 1| head -50', shell=True)`

Comment: forgot to add...dont want to invoke from shell.. so shell=False is what i need but then how do i use du like this ?

Comment: You'll figure it out. `subprocess` is the way to go.

Comment: It looks like the purpose of the greps is to keep the largest files ? You want to keep files with gigabyte size? Then you execute more `grep -v` commands to remove wrongfully matched files that had ##G in their name ?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ There are other more "pythonic" ways to achieve this. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45667428/5771861)

Comment: @ hakan baba - yes you are right in your assumption.. I will try the code you mentioned and update in a while. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this python program. It does not spawn any child processes in the shell.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 from __future__ import absolute_import
 from __future__ import print_function
 import subprocess
 import os
 import argparse

 def files_larger_than_no_child_process(min_bytes, count):
     """Return the top count files that are larger than the given min_bytes"""

     # A list that will have (size, name) tuples.
     file_info = []
     for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
         for f in files:
             file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root, f)))
             try:
                 size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
                 # Discard all smaller files than the given threshold
                 if size > min_bytes:
                     file_info.append((size,file_path))
             except OSError as e:
                 pass

     # Sort the files with respect to their sizes
     file_info = sorted(file_info, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)

     # Print the top count entries
     for l in file_info[:count]:
         print(l[0], " ", l[1])

 def main():
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("""Prints the top files that are larger than the
         given bytes in the current directory recusrively.""")
     parser.add_argument("min_bytes",help="Print files larger than this value",
         type=int)
     parser.add_argument("count",help="Print at most the given number of files",
         type=int)
     args = parser.parse_args()


     files_larger_than_no_child_process(args.min_bytes, args.count)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: i tried this code.. but getting the below OSError... then i added a try except block to catch that exception but still get it... what do you think is the problem here ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aspx/psharma1/scripts/diskusage2.py", line 38, in <module>
    files_larger_than_no_child_processes(100000,50)
  File "/home/aspx/psharma1/scripts/diskusage2.py", line 19, in files_larger_than_no_child_processes
    size=os.path.getsize(file_path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './proftp_1.3.5rc4/usr/proftp/proftpd-1.3.5rc4/lib/libltdl/.libs/libltdlc.la'

Comment: @pulkit Can you paste the error before you tried to handle it ?I would expect the error to come from `os.path.getsize(..)` function rather than the append function.

Comment: @pulkit. Looking at your other questions, it looks like you are new here. I strongly recommend to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: yes I'am new.. but i dont have enough prviliges yet.. i do vote which ever answers are helpful but it doesnt show as i need to have some min reputation for the votes to reflect

Comment: We will have to try something out here. What is the file  `./proftp_1.3.5rc4/usr/proftp/proftpd-1.3.5rc4/lib/libltdl/.‌​libs/libltdlc.la` ? What does `ls -all ./proftp_1.3.5rc4/usr/proftp/proftpd-1.3.5rc4/lib/libltdl/.‌​libs/libltdlc.la` return? Does this error happen at the first file or somewhere in the middle of the processing ?

Comment: it just says "no such file or dir"... i tried going into the dir further. but cant go further than "./proftp_1.3.5rc4/usr/proftp/proftpd-1.3.5rc4/lib/libltdl"

and the error happens somewhere in the middle of the processing,,not at the start

Comment: @pulkit I have also modified how the file_path is computed. You may want to try again. Not sure this it will fix your problem though. Also is there some other process that deletes the `./proftp_1.3.5rc4/usr/proftp/proftpd-1.3.5rc4/lib/libltdl/.‌‌​​libs/libltdlc.la` Are you sure that file still exists after the script exits with error ?

Comment: there are no cleanups running on this path . so dont think the file would be getting deleted by any process, though its possible i dont have access to them because as i said cant go further than "/lawdump/proftp_1.3.5rc4/usr/proftp/proftpd-1.3.5rc4/lib/libltdl"

I will try out the code again , will update

Comment: @pulkit. If the `ls -all` cannot find it, then maybe the ignoring the error is OK. I have edited the python code accordingly. Another question: Does the `du -ah`' s output contain that file ?

Comment: i tried the edited code... now it just prints all files without taking the size factor into account... 

2nd ques : yes du is showing that file... though its an empty file..

Comment: i commented out the print(file_path) part and trying again... because there are so many files that it will just go on..

Comment: @pulkit That surprises me a lot. You can try to paste your entire program here https://repl.it/KInd/0 . I can try to take a look at it.  Or even better: Create a directory with couple of files with different sizes in it. Try your program there and make sure it behaves as expected. That will help you understand what is going on before running it in a more populated dir.

Comment: @pulkit the print(file_name) was an accidental paste on my side.

Comment: it worked...i think we were printing before the try block so it was just priting everything before checking the size... so i commented print (file_path) and it gave me very close to what i was looking for... thanks a lot.. might get back to you on the same thread if i get stuck again... +1 for this answer :)

Comment: i modified the code a bit to pass the filesystem,min_bytes,count as arguments to the script but it keeps failing with the below error... i have pasted the code at the link you provided earlier.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aspx/psharma1/scripts/diskusage2.py", line 40, in <module>
    files_larger_than_no_child_processes(dirname,min_bytes,count)
  File "/home/aspx/psharma1/scripts/diskusage2.py", line 35, in files_larger_than_no_child_processes
    for l in file_info[:count]:
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: @pulkit I do not think you saved your code in repl.it link. But I think I know what your problem is. I have added command line processing to the answer. Take a look. PS: These are very fundamental concepts in Python. I hope you will have the interest and time to learn more by yourself at some point.

Comment: i appreciate all the help , but i did modify the code to suit command line parameters..and it works just fine when i replace all changes with the hardcoded version (though same values). i have pasted the code there...you can check if you get a chance and see if i need to start from scratch in some of the modules. thanks again for all the help btw :)

Comment: min_bytes=int(sys.argv[2]) Similarly for the count @pulkit