# Need to remove the extra empty lines from the output of shell script

Tags: shell, unix

i'm trying to write a code which will print all files taking more than min_size (lets say 10G) in a directory. the problem is output off the below code is all files irrespective of the min_size. i will be getting other details like mtime , owner as well later in the code but this part itself doesnt work fine, whats wrong here ?

```
#!/bin/sh

if (( $# <3 )); then
  echo "$0 dirname min_size count"
  exit 1
else
  dirname="$1";
  min_size="$2";
  count="$3";
  #shift 3
fi

tmpfile=$(mktemp /lawdump/pulkit/files.XXXXXX)
exec 3> "$tmpfile"
find "${dirname}" -type f -print0 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied" | xargs -0 -I {} echo "{}" > "$tmpfile"
for i in `cat tmpfile`
do
  x="`du -ah $i | awk '{print $1}' | grep G | sort -nr -k 1`"
  size=$(echo $x | sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g')
  if [ size > $min_size ];then
  echo $size
fi
done
```

Note : i know this can be done through find or du but i need to write a shell script to have an email sent out regularly with all the details.

Comment: `find` utility can find files by size `find "${dirname}" -size +"${min_size}" -type f"`. In your code `if [ size > $min_size ]` doesn't do what you thought it does. It should be `if (( size > min_size ))`. But please, stick to the `-size +${min_size}` instead.

Comment: Please see my note..I don't want to use find or du utilities.. need it in a shell script..

Comment: But you did use `find` in your script. Get rid of the `find` in your script then we'll give you non-find answer.

Comment: I said i dont want to use find or du as standalone commands.. i need a script to do other things as well and send out emails on regular basis if space usage breaches a certain level... and i dont think there should be any conditions here to provide answers unless ofcourse that is the only way.

Comment: You can use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659608/replicate-a-modified-du-command-in-python/45667428#45667428. It doesn't use `find` and doesn't use `du`.

Comment: I don't believe anyone will agree not to use `find`. Hence there won't be anyone going to post an answer. If for example I ask for a wheel that isn't round, will anyone suggest any type of wheel?

Comment: wow..dont know whats going on here. i thought i might ask a question and see where am i going wrong... anyways thanks . im out.

Comment: Again : i never said im not going to use find,. i said im not going to use them as standalone..